# how to take a value from array of object

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting array of object  from `service.ts` and store at `let dataStore:any =[];` but I can't print like `console.log(dataStore.title);` which is `undefined`

```
[{…}] 
0:
{_id: "5b588a11ffce060ef0d0b2d7", title: "todo", description: "filesss", completed: false, __v: 0}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Comment: `dataStore` is an array. Arrays do not have a `title` property.

Comment: Use dataStore[ndex].title.

Comment: i am getting this [{…}]
0
:
{_id: "5b5a8d9215b1fb1f1473be2b", title: "jaskdlosdj", description: "jkzdhkas", completed: true, __v: 0}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0) now how can i get value of title

Comment: thank u so much it work inside function

Answer (score 2):

dataStore is an array.

> An array can hold many values under a single name, and **you can access the values by referring to an index number**.

```js
var dataStore=[{_id: "5b588a11ffce060ef0d0b2d7", title: "todo", description: "filesss", completed: false, v: 0}]

console.log(dataStore[0].title)
```